# Cannot fetch date part of Timestamp only and compare it with java.sql.Date object

Tags: postgresql, scala, slick

I want to compare the

```
query filter {
  _._1.asOf === // how to compare it with date part only?
}
```

here `_._1.asOf` is of type `Rep[java.sql.Timestamp]`. What I want to do is to take only date part of this time stamp and compare it with `java.sql.Date.valueOf(dateString)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`java.util.Timestamp` is a subtype of `java.util.Date` so in which you can use the `getDate`, `getMonth`, `getYear`, then compare it's value with the output of `java.sql.Date.value(dateString)` using same getters.

Unsolicited advise, you Jodatime library in handling DateTime on jvm, you can use this: https://github.com/tototoshi/slick-joda-mapper as mapper for sql timestamp and jodatime.